# What adaptations does the human body have to handle frequent and sustained changes in orientation?

Tags: physiology, human-physiology

Most animals are horizontal with the ground.  When they lie down, they get closer to the ground, but their orientation does not change.

Humans, on the other hand, stand up straight and tall, perpendicular with the ground.  And when we lie down, we make a complete 90° turn.  So we spent 2/3 of our day at one orientation, and 1/3 of our day at the exactly orthogonal orientation.

It's difficult to think of many other animals that change their orientation so completely on a regular basis, or spend much time in different orientations.  (Sure, prairie dogs, bears, lemurs, and apes stand upright now and then, and I've seen pictures of whales sleeping vertically, but it's never for long, sustained periods.  Giraffes seem so tall and vertical, but it's all neck and legs — the organs of their body are always horizontal with the ground, and this orientation is maintained when they lie down.  Birds, maybe?)

For humans, regular changes in orientation must surely cause biological stresses, and therefore there must be some biological adaptations to those stresses.

Even non-biologists are aware of plenty of orientation-related malfunctions:
— middle-aged people start to get acid reflux and indigestion when they lie horizontally
— elderly people with certain heart conditions and arrhythmias cannot lie horizontally
— some people are affected by changes in blood pressure when they lie down or stand up
— some people have dizziness or balance issues when lying down or standing up
— knees and feet start to have problems from a lifetime of bearing all the weight

**What specific adaptations does the human body have to handle these daily changes in orientation?**

Comment: I guess posture would be a more appropriate term instead of orientation.

Comment: For "— some people are affected by changes in blood pressure when they lie down or stand up" and "— some people have dizziness or balance issues when lying down or standing up
", see the discussions of mechanisms in the Wikipedia articles for [Orthostatic Hypotension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthostatic_hypotension) and [Reflex Syncope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflex_syncope).

Comment: For "— knees and feet start to have problems from a lifetime of bearing all the weight", the protective adaptations will largely be identical to those for any joint - even those that aren't supporting the entire body. This can include processes like the release of [Synovial fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synovial_fluid).